# How to map 2 tables in hibernate at pojo class level?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oop

hi I have 2 pojo classes for DutyManager & DMSchedule

This is my database table details

Table Name,
Duty_Manager:       Manager_ID,  Title, Name, Age ,Address     PK=Manager_ID

DM_Schedule:        Schedule_ID , Manager_ID, From_Date, To_Date      PK=Schedule_ID                                                     FK=Manager_ID

How should i need to map in POJO class level by using hibernate annotation.

Comment: What is the relationship between DutyManager and DMSchedule?

Comment: @Thihara Sry I forget to mention It's One-Many...:)

Comment: One security manager many schedules? Then you can have a Collection of schedules in the security manager.

Comment: Yea I wanna to know how to map that at POJO Level Classes by using Hibernate annotations

Comment: smajlo have given the answer. Although you may be better off going through the docs first.....

Comment: @Yasa What have you tried then? This should be a plenty straight forward task if you have briefly read the documents or tutorials

Comment: @adrianShum I tried as normal way as single pojo class, I didn't add private DutyManager manager; in DMSchedule class, I didn't have idea by that time, anyway noted your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Duty_Manager")
public class DutyManager {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName = "MNG_SEQ")
@Column(name = "MANAGER_ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "manager_title", nullable = false)
private String title;
@Column(name = "manager_name", nullable = false)
private String name;
@Column(name = "manager_age", nullable = false)
private int age;

public DutyManager() {
}


//getters and setters
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "DM_Schedule")
public class DM_Schedule {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName = "SCH_SEQ")
@Column(name = "Schedule_ID")
private Long id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "manager_id", nullable = false)
private DutyManager manager;
@Column(name = "date_from", nullable = false)
private Date from;
@Column(name = "date_to", nullable = false)
private Date to;

public DM_Schedule() {
}


//getters and setters
}
```

EDit:
As mentioned in comments you can also keep `Collection<DM_Schedule>` in `Manager` class annotated by `@OneToMany` annotation.