# Hibernate @Any annotation usage

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, polymorphism, any

I have one entity called Change where I need log changes in database like inserting, updating or deleting rows.

So my Change table contains some data and now I would like to add foreign key to record changes in another table, but I have different tables. For example I have Weather table, Group table,... So I have done some searching and I have found a little bit about @Any annotation. So I added some columns to my Change entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHANGE")
public class Change {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CHANGE_ID")
    private int changeId;
...
@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "RECORD_TABLE"))
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "int", metaType = "string",
metaValues = {
@MetaValue(targetEntity = Weather.class, value = "WEATHER"),
@MetaValue(targetEntity = Group.class, value = "GROUP"),
...
})
@JoinColumn(name="recordID")
private Object record;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;

public Object getRecord() {
    return record;
}
public void setRecord(Object record) {
    this.record = record;
}
...
```

And my stupid question is: 
How can I insert data into database (like foreign ID and class name) and how could I retrieve them?

Answer (score -1):

Please go through this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130584/how-to-map-2-tables-in-hibernate-at-pojo-class-level)

You should care about your entity relationship (1-1 or 1-M or M-M)

Comment: I am afraid that I have to use different relationship than (1-1,1-M,N-M). I can use these when I know table to which I am referencing, but I can referece to multiple tables here (like GROUP, WEATHER, etc.) and I need identify table name and record in it.  So I think that I must use polymorphic relationship. It's similar to this: http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_the_any_annotation. But I don't know how to set or get Object item, how can I call change.setRecord("int id, String name")...